# EDM Query associations

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

The good thing about the entity framework is, that it hides
the complete n..m association problem.

Now I have some really simple Database containing

```
Person (Id, Name)
Profession (Id, Designation)
```

there is a n..m association between those two, meaning every person can
have many Professions and every Profession can be executed by many Persons.
This association is built on the Id in each entity.

Now I want to have exactly those Associations, but there seems to be no way
to get those.

If I query a Person like

```
using (PersonDataModelContainer dmc = new PersonDataModelContainer())
{
    var persons = (from p in dmc.Persons
                   where p.Id == personId
                   select p).ToList();
}
```

There is a member "Profession", but it is empty.
In the Associationstable there are entries that correspond
to this Person.Id.

I see somewhere down in the single object this query returns that 
there are the relations in a non public member.

How can I read those? Should not be that hard I believe, but I could
not find it out via google.

Comment: should be 4.1, not quite sure about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (PersonDataModelContainer dmc = new PersonDataModelContainer())
{
    var persons =  dmc.Persons
                   .Include("Profession")
                   .Where(p.Id == personId)
                   .ToList();
}
```

Comment: @TomasVoracek WHAT? what if I have an entity that has 250 navigation properties? will EF load them all?! That makes no sense. Either with Lazy Loading or w/o it, you specify (either explicitly via `Include` or implicitly via accesing the navigation properties in code) what you need to load

Comment: this works perfectly for me. Thank you very much! p.s. is there any tutorial or website, where I can find a better start on the EF issue?

Comment: @TomasVoracek I know what lazy loading is, but your statement that "EF4 should load associations automatically" is rather false